# Following Agile web development but Im getting errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following Agile web development. I am at the unit testing phase of the book. I've followed it to a tee. But I am getting the following errors when I run rake:test units

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
/Users/ray/Desktop/work/depot/test/models/product_test.rb:15:in `test'
/Users/ray/Desktop/work/depot/test/models/product_test.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-  4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `require'
/Users/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-  4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/Users/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/Users/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
Tasks: TOP => test:units
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

my test/models/product_test.rb looks like the following:

```
require 'test_helper'

 class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    fixtures :products
   test "product attributes must not be empty" do 
  product = Product.new
  assert product.invalid?
  assert product.errors[:title].any?
  assert product.errors[:description].any?
   assert product.errors[:price].any?
   assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
  end
 end

 test "product price must be positive" do
     product = Product.new(title:        "My Book Title",
                      description:  "yyy",
                      image_url:    "zzz.jpg")
    product.price = -1
    assert product.invalid?
    assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01", 
      product.errors[:price].join('; ')

    product.price = 0
    assert product.invalid?
    assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01", 
     product.errors[:price].join('; ')

    product.price = 1
    assert product.valid?
  end

  def new_product(image_url)
    Product.new(title:       "My Book Title",
                description: "yyy",
                price:       1,
                image_url:   image_url)
  end

  test "image url" do
    ok = %w{ fred.gif fred.jpg fred.png FRED.JPG FRED.Jpg
             http://a.b.c/x/y/z/fred.gif }
    bad = %w{ fred.doc fred.gif/more fred.gif.more }

    ok.each do |name|
      assert new_product(name).valid?, "#{name} shouldn't be invalid"
    end

    bad.each do |name|
      assert new_product(name).invalid?, "#{name} shouldn't be valid"
    end
  end

  test "product is not valid without a unique title" do
    product = Product.new(title:        products(:ruby).title,
                          description:  "yyy", 
                          price:        1, 
                          image_url:    "fred.gif")

    assert !product.save
    assert_equal "has already been taken", product.errors[:title].join('; ')
  end

  test "product is not valid without a unique title - i18n" do
    product = Product.new( title:        products(:ruby).title,
                       description:  "yyy", 
                       price:        1, 
                       image_url:    "fred.gif")

    assert !product.save
    assert_equal I18n.translate('activerecord.errors.messages.taken'),
                 product.errors[:title].join('; ')
  end
```

my test/fixtures/products.yml looks like this

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

one:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: MyString
  price: 9.99

two:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: MyString
  price: 9.99

ruby:
    title: Programming Ruby 1.9 
    description:
        Ruby is the fastest growing and most exciting dynamic
        language out there.  If you need to get working programs
        delivered fast, you should add Ruby to your toolbox.
    price: 49.50 
    image_url: ruby.png
```

I am really new to rails any nod in the right direction, or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit

heres my app/models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
    validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :title, uniqueness: true

    validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: { 
      with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
      message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
      }
end
```

Comment: Looks like the error message is being thrown from the `product = Product.new(...` line. Could you post the content of `app/models/product.rb` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test file - `test/models/product_test.rb` - syntax is wrong; and that is causing the error message. There are two `end` statements on line 12 & 13 of that file. Remove one of them and put it at the end of the file; that will fix this problem.

Because of that extra `end` at line 12, the test file is considered complete at that point, and the next line is interpreted in a different context causing the problem.